# How to add a label in a settings screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, application-settings

As a picture says more than a thousand words:
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091008-k16k7we3t43gj3h7htgtjpunpx.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091008-k16k7we3t43gj3h7htgtjpunpx.jpg)

Any help on how to add descriptive labels to a settings pane would be highly appreciated!
I should point out that I want to do this to be in the iPhone-App settings that are in the Settings menu of the iPhone (**outside the App**).

Example label:

- iPhone -> Settings -> Safari -> Fraud Warning
- The label beneath: "Warn when visiting fraudulent websites."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple has not given iPhone developers the capability to add the kind of label you're looking for in Settings.app. As a near approximation, I've used `PSGroupSpecifier` under another setting element (such as `PSToggleSwitchSpecifier`). It's not as elegant as a true label, but it worked well enough in my situation (I only had one setting, so it didn't conflict with any other group headings).

[alt text http://pseudorandomengineer.com/images/6.png](http://pseudorandomengineer.com/images/6.png)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I also tried. Unfortunately it looks not that "elegant"… Nevertheless, thank you for your answer!

Comment: No problem. I thought I ought to add it for future reference, just in case it's suitable for someone else. :-)

Answer (score 4):

For reference: Since iOS4.0 and above a FooterText key was added to PSGroupSpecifier that does exactly what you are looking for.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference.pdf (pg 11)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `PSTitleValueSpecifier` in your settings bundle's plist. I'm not sure how that formats itself—most likely bold, like the group headers—but it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like a setting - just one you cant edit. Looks like I'm out of luck with my labels…

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a label that is center-justified, add an empty title PSGroupSpecifier and put your label text in the FooterText Key.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [`tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW4) method of `UITableViewDataSource`. You can return a string to be displayed below a table view section. If you're already using a `UITableViewController` subclass, just implement that method and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have pointed out more clearly that I want this to be in the iPhone-App settings that are in the Settings menu of the iPhone (outside the App).

I bet there is no  way to achieve this there…?